# Do Cython files break the Community Edition (Free) PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, cython

So, the free edition of PyCharm does not support Cython (unlike the paid version). What does this mean? Will it break if I have any *pyx files in my project directory, or refuse to work with those files in any way, or ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/5.0/cython-support.html):

> Cython support includes:
>
> Coding assistance: 
> Error and syntax highlighting.
> Code completion for keywords, fields of structs, and attributes of extension types.
> Code formatting and folding.
> Ability to create line comments (⌘/).
> Cython syntax for typed memoryviews.
> Code inspections. Almost all Python code inspections work for Cython.
> Refactorings.
> Numerous ways to navigate through the source code, among them:
> Navigating with Structure View.
> Navigate | Declaration (⌘B).
> Navigate | Implementation (⌥⌘B) from overridden method / subclassed class.
> Advanced facilities to search through the source code, in particular, finding usages.
> Compiling Cython modules:
> Compilation is done using external tools. The preferred build systems (Makefile, setup.py, etc.) should be configured as external tools.
> C compiler should be downloaded and installed on your computer.

The free version just gives you a text editor view of your .pyx, .pxi, and .pxd files, just like any other file it doesn't know what to do with.